# Los elementos no se muestran/ocultan correctamente al hacer búsqueda

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Estoy haciendo un buscador interno con varios criterios de busca, pero la tabla donde muestra los resultado la mantengo oculta con `display:none` y solo aparece cuando el usuario hace click en "buscar". Antes de mostrar los resultado tengo una barra de loader.

Mi problema es que cuando hago click en "buscar", la barra no aparece y la tabla con el resultado de la búsqueda aparece y desaparece en seguida. ¿Cómo hago para resolver ese problema em mi código?

Éste es mi código:

```js
$("#btn_buscar").click(function() {

  // barra de progress
  $('#loader').html('<img src="imagens/loader/ajax-loader.gif" />')


  //Mostrar la div oculta
  $('#resultadoBusca').show();

  //Recibe los datos del formulário
  var dados = $("#buscador_dash").serialize();
  $.post("dashboard.php", dados, function(retorna) {
    $("#msg").slideDown('slow').html(retorna);

    //Limpiar los campos
    $('#buscador_dash')[0].reset();



  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="buscador_dash" action="dashboard.php" method="POST" name="buscador_dash">

  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0">
        <label class="control-label-2">ORIGEM</label>
        <input type="text" id="buscar_origem" name="buscar_origem" class="form-control search-slt" placeholder="Insira sua cidade de origem" required="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0">
        <label class="control-label-2">DESTINO</label>
        <input type="text" id="buscar_destino" name="buscar_destino" class="form-control search-slt" placeholder="Insira sua cidade de destino" required="">

      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0">
        <label class="control-label-2">DATA</label>
        <input type="date" id="buscar_data" name="buscar_data" class="form-control search-slt" required="">

      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12 p-0">

        <label class="control-label-2"></label>
        <button type="submit" id="btn_procurar" name="btn_procurar" class="btn btn-primary wrn-btn" value="procurar">
               <i class="fas fa-search" style="margin-right:10px;"></i>
               <strong>Procurar</strong>
             </button>


      </div>
</form>
```

```
<div class="row-box3" id="resultadoBusca" style="padding: 10px;  margin-top: 10px; display:none; " > <!--div row-box3-->

                             <div class="table table-sm table-responsive-sm">
            <table class="table table-striped thead-dark" style="font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">

                <tr>

                  <th>Cia</th>
                  <th>Origem</th>
                  <th>Destino</th>
                  <th>Saída</th>
                  <th>Volta</th>
                  <th>Valor</th>
                  <th></th>

                </tr>
                <span  id="msg"></span>
                <?php
                  $buscar_origem = '';
                  $buscar_destino ='';
                  $buscar_data ='';

      if(isset($_POST){
          @$buscar_origem = $_POST['buscar_origem'];
          @$buscar_destino = $_POST['buscar_destino'];
          @$buscar_data = $_POST['buscar_data'];




      $slq_busca =" SELECT * FROM escurcao  WHERE origem like '".$buscar_origem."' AND destino like '".$buscar_destino."' AND data_ida like '%".$buscar_data ."%' ";

                $rs = $mysqli->query($slq_busca);

                $total = mysqli_num_rows($rs);
                  if($total>0){
                 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $rs)){ 


                  echo '
                  <tr>
                  <td><img id="img_table_dash"  src="imagens/img_agencias/img_logos/'. $row['idUsuario'].'/short_logo.png"/></td>
                  <td id="td_dash" >'.$row['origem'].'</td>
                  <td id="td_dash" >'.$row['destino'].'</td>
                  <td>'.date ('d/m/y ', strtotime($row['data_ida'])).'&nbsp '.date ('H:i ', strtotime($row['horas_ida'])).'h</td>
                  <td>'.date ('d/m/y ', strtotime($row['data_volta'])).' &nbsp'.date ('H:i', strtotime($row['horas_volta'])).'h</td>
                  <td>'.number_format ($row['valor'], 2,",", ".").'</td>
                  <td><a href="modificar.php?Detalhes-Excurssão='.$row['id_escurcao'].';"><span class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></span></a></td>


                  </tr>


                  ';

                }//while
                  }else{
                    echo '<h3 style="color:red; text-align:center;">Nenhuma disponibilidade encontrada.</h3>';
                  }

                  }//empty

                ?>


            <!--
              <td><a href="#"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editar_quarto" data-whatever="'.$row['id_tipo_quarto'].'" data-whatever-cod_escurcao="'.$row['escurname'].'" data-whatever-tipoquarto2="'.$row['cod_tipo2'].'" data-whatever-num_quarto="'.$row['num_quarto'].'" data-whatever-valor="'.$row['valor_diaria'].'"><span class="fas fa-pencil-alt" ></span></a></td>
            -->

            </table>
          </div> 


                            </div> <!--div row-box3-->
```

Comment: Hola everson, el código compartido no es HTML válido (algunas etiquetas no se están cerrando correctamente). No sé si ese es el problema, pero podría ser algo a mirar. También, ¿recibes algún error en la consola del navegador?

Comment: Le estás insertando el **gif** del **loader** a un elemento `#loader` pero en tu **HTML** no existe ningún elemento que posea dicha **id**. También estás tratando de hacer un `show()` de otro elemento inexistente: `#resultadoBusca`

Comment: Revisando el código JavaScript, no hay nada que oculte la tabla. Creo que puede faltar código esencial en la pregunta para resolver el problema.

Comment: @phpMyGuel en JavaScript puro eso daría un error y pararía la ejecución, pero jQuery se traga el error y la ejecución sigue de forma normal.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Exacto. Pero una de las cosas que el **OP** dice es que no se le ve el "loader", de ahí mi aportación. No se puede ver algo que no se está insertando en el **DOM**.

Comment: @phpMyGuel tengo que prestar más atención al leer :-/

Comment: El codigo html no lo he puesto completo por eso el `#resultadoBusca` no aparece mas ya vou a editarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver mi problema quitando  el atributo `ACTION` y cambiando el `type="submit"`por `type="button"`de mi codigo html.

Comment: wow, increíble que todos esos usuarios no hayan podido ayudarte a resolver ese problema tan simple.

Comment: @ the-breaker , eso es normal talvez no entendieron la pregunta, o lo que ocurrio de no colocar todo el codigo, pero eso de no tener una respuesta para un problema es bueno, asi acabas aprendiendo de los errores.